# facebook login when to store user data

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to figure out at what point in the Facebook user login flow I can store their data. My app will ask for the user's email so that we can contact them, but I'm not sure *when* in the code I'm supposed to store their info to my database.

And here it is again:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '255450714496176', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
            // logged in and connected user, someone you know
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
              alert("Welcome, " + response.name);
            });
          } else {
            // no user session available, someone you dont know
            alert("logged out");
          }
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
            alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);          
        });

  }; // fbAsyncInit

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code that you have given, you can store data in `FB.getLoginStatus`, within the `if(response.authResponse)` block.